# Docker network and container use the LAN

Tags: linux, networking, docker, container

I have a LAN with `192.168.2.0/24`.

A docker machine with two network cards

```
eth0: 192.168.2.150/24
eth1: 192.168.2.151/24
```

I use `192.168.2.150` to manage the docker machine.

I want to broadcast the service of a container on the LAN at `192.168.2.151`

How should I configure the network ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `host` network mode in docker:

```bash
docker run --network host --ip 192.168.2.151 image_name
```

When you use the `host` network mode, the container has direct access to the host network interfaces and can broadcast packets to the host network.